# Find value in array and use filter function to hide filtered elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filtering

I am trying to filter a given result list. Therefore I am using a `ul` list for the results and checkboxes for the filter options.

The items in the `ul` list carry `data` attributes. If a checkbox with `value="4711"` is clicked, all `li`, that do not have a `data` attribute with `value="4711"` should be hidden from that list.

I am totally stuck on this, as I do not have much knowledge in the work with arrays.

```js
var values = "";
var values_arr = [];
var data = "";
var data_arr = [];

function filterelements() {
  $("#filter input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
    values = $(this).value;
    values_arr.push(values);
  });

  $("#results li").each(function() {
    data = $(this).data("sample");
    data_arr = str.split(",");
  });

  console.log("Values: " + values_arr);
  console.log("Data attribute: " + data_arr);

  for (i = 0; i < values_arr.length; i++) {
    // Search in Array
    console.log('Index : ' + values_arr.indexOf(values));
    if (values_arr.indexOf(values) == -1) {
      console.log("not existing");
      $(this).parent("li").hide();
    }
  }
}

$("#filter :checkbox").on("click", function() {
  filterelements();
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<h4>Filter:</h4>
<div id="filter">
  <input type="checkbox" id="el_123" value="123"><label for="el_123">123</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="el_9" value="9"><label for="el_9">9</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="el_13" value="13"><label for="el_13">13</label>
</div>


<h4 class="mt-3">Results</h4>
<ul id="results">
  <li data-sample="123,17,24">Line 1</li>
  <li data-sample="13,26,12">Line 2</li>
  <li data-sample="123,9">Line 3</li>
  <li data-sample="13,17,2, 9">Line 4</li>
</ul>

<p>
  Description:<br>If a filter checkbox is clicked, all &lt;li&gt;'s should be hidden, that do not have the checkbox value in its data-attribute.
</p>
```

My current try can be found here: https://www.bootply.com/9dXfEeXsWb. Any ideas and recommendations how to move on from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check status of checkboxs in change event listener. If is checked use  `.filter()` to filtering elements hasn't input value in `data-sample` and hide them. If is not checked show all items.

```js
$("#filter :checkbox").change(function(){
  if ($(this).is(":checked")){
    var val = this.value;
    $("#results li").filter(function(){
      return $(this).data("sample").split(",").indexOf(val) == -1;
    }).hide();
  } else
    $("#results li").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Filter:</h4>
<div id="filter">
    <input type="checkbox" id="el_123" value="123"><label for="el_123">123</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="el_9" value="9"><label for="el_9">9</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="el_13" value="13"><label for="el_13">13</label>
</div>
<h4 class="mt-3">Results</h4>
<ul id="results">
  <li data-sample="123,17,24">Line 1 (contain 123,17,24)</li>
  <li data-sample="13,26,12">Line 2 (contain 13,26,12)</li>
  <li data-sample="123,9">Line 3 (contain 123,9)</li>
  <li data-sample="13,17,2,9">Line 4 (contain 13,17,2,9)</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for investing your time on this.... looks "easy" know as I see it. And makes 100% sense to me. I'll try to recognize a solution like this next time I am facing a similar problem. Thank you again!!